# Monitor Raspberry Pi GPIO pin change with libevent

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, libevent

I have a server (C++) relying on libevent to detect various events like incoming network connections and traffic, running on a raspberry pi. In addition to network ports I'd also like to monitor a few Raspberry PI's GPIO pins for changes triggered by buttons (low/high or high/low transitions). Of course, I could spawn a thread with a polling loop, but I'd prefer to leave this to libevent (maybe with a little help from the OS, or however this could work).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46231332/4614700) indicates that a select-based solution is possible. This brings me half-way, but if possible I'd like to stick to libevent. I am not an export on libevent (merely a user), therefore I am unsure how the select option helps (or maybe not).

I'd be really grateful for a "pure libevent" solution. Thanks for any hints to make it work!

Comment: Not familiar with `libevent` but the code here shows how to have a function executed as a callback when a rising or falling edge occurs on a GPIO pin. Maybe you could run that and generate a `libevent`-type of event from the callback handler... https://github.com/phil-lavin/raspberry-pi-gpio-interrupt/blob/master/gpio-interrupt.c

Comment: Thanks for the hint, that looks doable in principle. However, interrupts are not ideal, since creating an event structure amounts to allocating memory. Well, I could of course pre-allocate a reasonably sized pool of events, since button presses are somewhat rare. Still, in terms of concurrency that would probably yield a quite hacky solution. I may be better off with a polling thread.